# modify url_for, a href for Symfony with JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, symfony1

I have :

```
<span id="test"><a href="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id='. $id) ?>">link1</a></span> <br />
```

or

```
<span id="test"><a href="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=') ?>" $id>link2</a></span>
```

I must generate url with url_for. i would like modify $id with javascript (jquery) if i click:

```
<span class="click" id=1>click one</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=2>click two</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=3>click three</span> <br />
```

if i click "CLICK ONE" the i would like link:

```
<span id="test"><a href="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=1') ?>">link1</a></span>
```

OR

```
<span id="test"><a href="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=') ?>"1>link2</a></span>
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/wtAbp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put each URL in a ref attribute for each span, like so:

```
<span class="click" id=1 rel="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=1') ?>">click one</span>
<span class="click" id=2 rel="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=2') ?>">click two</span>
<span class="click" id=3 rel="<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=3') ?>">click three</span>
```

And then in your click event (or whichever way you chose), replace the target's href with the clicked element's rel value.

```
$('.click').unbind('click').click(function() {
  $('a#your_id').attr('href', $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code `<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=1') ?>` is interpreted on the server side. So you can't modify it on the client side.

Just put `"<?php echo url_for('mymodule/myaction?id=') ?>"` in the href, without the id, and add dynamicaly the id :

Something like :

```
$(".click").live('click', function() {    
    $("a").attr('href',$("a").attr('href')+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```